# Is there a dedicated solr function to return index?

Tags: php, solr

I tried following the basic example of solr in php from the official docs (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php).

I wanted to write a function that simply return the solr index.

For example, consider the following code:

```
$options = array( 'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME );
$client = new SolrClient($options);
$doc = new SolrInputDocument();
$doc->addField('id', 12345);
$doc->addField('title', 'Stack Overflow');
$client->addDocument($doc);
$client->commit();
```

This works perfectly. But, lets say I wanted to write a function that simply returns me the solr index. For example:

```
function get_index(){
   $index = //something here
   ...
   return $index;
}
```

How can I do this? Is this possible? I'm new to solr and I'm using the PECL Solr client.(http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to examples #4 & #5 from the [Examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php) page for the Solr PECL client. Then you can build a query that searches across and returns all fields, like the following:

```
 $options = array (
     'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
     'port'     => SOLR_SERVER_PORT);
 $client = new SolrClient($options);
 $query = new SolrQuery();
 $query->setQuery('*:*');  // *:* means search all fields for all values.
 $query->setStart(0);
 $query->setRows(100000); //very large to ensure all rows are returned.
 $query->addField('*'); // * will return all fields
 $query_response = $client->query($query);
 $query_response->setParseMode(SolrQueryResponse::PARSE_SOLR_DOC);
 $response = $query_response->getResponse();
 print_r($response);
```

For more details on querying Solr and the options that you can use, please refer to the following:

- [Searching in Solr](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Searching)
- [Solr Query Syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) & [Common Query Parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)